# Is there any way to define a command such that it prints page numbers of its argument in the whole document?

Tags: macros, indexing, imakeidx, makeindex

Is there any way to define a command such that it prints page numbers of pages containing the exact word of its argument in the whole document?

For example call this command `\mycmd{}`. by using `\mycmd{manifold}` I want to have a list of all page numbers of pages containing `manifold`! Is it possible at all?

I want to use this in index page for simplicity.

Comment: For indices look at the [imakeidx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/imakeidx) package.

Comment: basically no, you need to mark each use with `\index`  tex never access the text in a way accessible to the macro layer so you can't do this automatically. Of course your editor can easily replace every use of manifold by manifold\index{manifold} or if using luatex you could do the replacement on the fly in a Lua callback.